# Domain path repeats in URL in loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I´ve been looking but I couldn't find an answer that suits my problem.

The thing is that my web is repeating the path in the URL in loop. For example: you can access domain.com/path/info.html or you can access domain.com/path/domain.com/path/domain.com/path/domain.com/path/...(here is the loop).../info.html

For the normal user it isn't a problem since he always uses the normal way but, for SEO, is a nightmare.

It probably has to do with the htaccess but we have no idea what could it give this issue. Could you help us? Thank you very much!

I leave you the htaccess in question (at least the rewriting rules of it):

```
   <ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>

FileETag None


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Compressing output.
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css application/json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml application/xml text/x-component
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype
</Ifmodule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    ##Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{HTTP_ORIGIN}e" env=HTTP_ORIGIN
    ##Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
    ##Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control, Content-MD5, X-Alt-Referer"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"   
    ##Header add Access-Control-Max-Age 1728000
</IfModule>


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite rules
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
AddHandler text/html .htm
AddType text/html .htm

DirectoryIndex index.php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html .xml
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^api /apirest.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/someindividualpage.htm
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_upload
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$    index.php


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite rules: Courses
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*?)/?$ index.php?url=$1&page=$2 [L]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$    index.php [L]
```